# When create django table dynamically, how can I set Meta class?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django abstract model class and want to create it dynamically with meta class.

```py
class AccountTransaction(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    account_num = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tran_amt = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    tran_type = models.CharField()
    tran_detail = models.CharField()
    tran_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

for i in range(10):
    model_name = f'account_transaction_{i:02}'
    globals()[model_name] = type(model_name, (AccountTransaction, ), {'__module__': AccountTransaction.__module__})
```

I could create 10 tables with this code when execute `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Is it possible to set different metaclasses for each tables?

For example,

**account_transaction_01**

```
class Meta:
    db_table: "table1"
```

**account_transaction_02**

```
class Meta:
    db_table: "table2"
```

Comment: What is the case which need to do what you are posted ?

Comment: I'm trying to develop a banking system and want to make many tables to save transactions that have the same fields without duplicated code. But I don't know how to set the table name.

Comment: Why you can not set all transactions in only one table, it is unclear

Comment: I have a hash function to divide each account to table. I know this logic can be wrong. I wonder if the technical part of my question is possible, not the logical part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have to make more of just implement an abstract base for going to your purpose, but it is possible i think. But probably not a good idea for the future maintenability of project...

Django has a internal mecanism for recognizing a model and you can create dynamically types whiches Django recognize as model.

An article in the Django wiki can help you, but be care, it is an old article:
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Hope it helps you

Good luck